# Exibir avatar em produtos woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Gostaria de saber uma maneira de exibir o avatar e nome do usuário na single do produto do woocommerce cadastrado.

Comment: Tentou usar o `get_avatar()` ?

Comment: Você fala o Thumb do produto? A imagem destacada?

Comment: Com get_avatar não funciona, já tentei. Estou falando da imagem de quem postou mesmo, não do produto em si.